# Stack Exchange Data Explorer uses deprecated reCAPTCHA

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I tried to run a query in Stack Exchange Data Explorer without being signed in. Doing so, I was presented with a reCAPTCHA that seems to be deprecated.

I was running this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65470/top-users-from-your-city

And I see this:

[image]

Comment: @PeterMortensen Looks like you use a reCAPTCHA Mailhide link in your profile description. That will also be deprecated along with reCAPTCHA v1.